# How to fix: XSLT 3.0 conditional filtering (if) issues

Tags: xslt-3.0

'If' condition inside for-each loop does not work. Based on the Region code from input file and cross reference file, some messages with certain country code need to be not produced.

for example if the input message contains country code CH which is not in input message, the payload should not be produced as a output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array" xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:err="http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors" exclude-result-prefixes="array fn map math xhtml xs err" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="xslt.transform.params">DE|AT|UK|IE|NL</xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="vCountryCode">
        <xsl:value-of select="$xslt.transform.params"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:param name="xslt.location.uriXSLTPath">
        <xsl:text>\app</xsl:text>
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="uriXSLT">
        <xsl:value-of select="$xslt.location.uriXSLTPath"/>
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="vSupplierFullPath" select="string(concat($uriXSLT,'/SupplierCrossReference.xml'))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vSupplierCrossReferences" select="document($vSupplierFullPath)/*:SupplierCrossReferences"/>
    <xsl:template match="/advice_file/product" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:text>"warehouses": [</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="warehouseBreakout/warehouse">
            <xsl:variable name="vVendor" select="../../vendor"/>
            <xsl:variable name="vWH" select="@warehouse-id"/>
            <xsl:variable name="vReg" select="fn:copy-of($vSupplierCrossReferences/SupplierCrossReference[TraitID=$vVendor]/warehouses/warehouse[@id=$vWH])"/>
            <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>"warehouseId" : "</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select=" fn:concat($vVendor,'-', $vWH)"/>
            <xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>"quantity" : </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="qtyonhand"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="next_available/@quantity != '' and next_available/@quantity !=0 ">
                    <xsl:variable name="vNextDate" select="next_available/@date"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:text>"nextAvailableDate": "</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fn:concat(fn:substring($vNextDate,1,4),'-',fn:substring($vNextDate,5,2),'-',fn:substring($vNextDate,7,2))"/>
                    <xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:text>"nextAvailableQuantity": </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="next_available/@quantity"/>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:text>,"servicedRegion" : [</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="$vReg//region">
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:variable name="vRegionCode" select="."/>
                <h3>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$vRegionCode"/>
                </h3>
                <xsl:if test="fn:contains($vCountryCode,$vRegionCode)">
                    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:if test="fn:position() != fn:last()">
                        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>]}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input Message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<advice_file as-of-date="2019-06-20T09:45:10.882+01:00" advice-content="incr">
    <advice_file_control_number>1561020310882</advice_file_control_number>
    <product last-update-date="2019-06-20T08:48:22.583+01:00">
        <vendor_SKU>AW23377-GY</vendor_SKU>
        <qtyonhand>390</qtyonhand>
        <available>YES</available>
        <next_available_qty>0</next_available_qty>
        <vendor>393</vendor>
        <warehouseBreakout>
            <warehouse warehouse-id="No merchant (warehouse)ID has been provided.">
                <qtyonhand>390</qtyonhand>
                <next_available quantity="0"/>
            </warehouse>
        </warehouseBreakout>
    </product>
    <product last-update-date="2019-06-20T08:48:22.583+01:00">
        <vendor_SKU>AW22226-WH</vendor_SKU>
        <qtyonhand>250</qtyonhand>
        <available>YES</available>
        <next_available_qty>0</next_available_qty>
        <vendor>342</vendor>
        <warehouseBreakout>
            <!--<warehouse warehouse-id="No merchant (warehouse)ID has been provided.">-->
            <warehouse warehouse-id="01">
                <qtyonhand>250</qtyonhand>
                <next_available quantity="0"/>
            </warehouse>
        </warehouseBreakout>
    </product>
    <product last-update-date="2019-06-20T09:40:11.797+01:00">
        <vendor_SKU>EL-FC22</vendor_SKU>
        <qtyonhand>734</qtyonhand>
        <available>YES</available>
        <min_days_to_fulfill>3</min_days_to_fulfill>
        <UPC>4016946199445</UPC>
        <next_available_qty>0</next_available_qty>
        <vendor>364</vendor>
        <warehouseBreakout>
            <warehouse warehouse-id="01">
                <qtyonhand>734</qtyonhand>
                <next_available quantity="0"/>
            </warehouse>
        </warehouseBreakout>
    </product>
    <advice_file_count>298</advice_file_count>
</advice_file>
```

Actual Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    "warehouses": [{"warehouseId" : "393-No merchant (warehouse)ID has been provided.","quantity" : 390,"servicedRegion" : []}]}
    "warehouses": [{"warehouseId" : "342-01","quantity" : 250,"servicedRegion" : ["<h3>CH</h3>]}]}
    "warehouses": [{"warehouseId" : "364-01","quantity" : 734,"servicedRegion" : ["<h3>DE</h3>","<h3>AT</h3>"]}]}
```

Expected Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    "warehouses": [{"warehouseId" : "393-No merchant (warehouse)ID has been provided.","quantity" : 390,"servicedRegion" : []}]}
    "warehouses": [{"warehouseId" : "364-01","quantity" : 734,"servicedRegion" : ["<h3>DE</h3>","<h3>AT</h3>"]}]}
```

Reference file:

```
<SupplierCrossReference name="Franken">
        <TraitID>364</TraitID>
        <!--<STEPSupplierID>SUPP_8888888</STEPSupplierID>-->
        <!-- NOTE the _C_ added as a tempory fix for Product stream POC -->
        <STEPSupplierID>SUPP_C_888888</STEPSupplierID>
        <STEPSuppliers>
            <Supplier store="DE">**********</Supplier>
            <Supplier store="AT">**********</Supplier>
        </STEPSuppliers>
        <AS400SupplierID>621</AS400SupplierID>
        <LegacySenderReceiverID>DE-FRANK2</LegacySenderReceiverID>
        <LegacySenderReceiverID>AT-FRANK2</LegacySenderReceiverID>
        <ComsysSenderReceiverID>DE-FRANK4</ComsysSenderReceiverID>
        <ComsysSenderReceiverID>AT-FRANK4</ComsysSenderReceiverID>
        <warehouses>
            <warehouse id='01'>
                <region>DE</region>
                <region>AT</region>
            </warehouse>
        </warehouses>
    </SupplierCrossReference>
```

Comment: Consider to show a sample of the file you reference. Also try to reduce the code to a minimum to demonstrate the problem. In general, if you want to filter on a higher level then add a predicate with the condition on `match="/advice_file/product"`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The reference file content updated.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the sample there in a well-formatted way, don't ask us to read code in comments.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Question updated with details. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so in your **XSL** you had:

```
<xsl:variable name="vSupplierCrossReferences" select="document($vSupplierFullPath)/*:SupplierCrossReferences"/>
```

But that's wrong, because the **cross-reference file** you gave only had:

```
<SupplierCrossReference name="Franken">
```

As the root. So changing it to the *singular* got me access to the cross reference file nodes in the XSL.

Another mistake was:

```
<xsl:variable name="vReg" select="fn:copy-of($vSupplierCrossReferences/SupplierCrossReference[TraitID=$vVendor]/warehouses/warehouse[@id=$vWH])"/>
```

I changed it to:

```
<xsl:variable name="vReg" select="fn:copy-of($vSupplierCrossReferences[TraitID=$vVendor]/warehouses/warehouse[@id=$vWH])"/>
```

With the data you gave, that gets us a lot closer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    1561020310882
    "warehouses": [{"warehouseId" : "393-No merchant (warehouse)ID has been provided.","quantity" : 390,"servicedRegion" : []}]}
    "warehouses": [{"warehouseId" : "342-01","quantity" : 250,"servicedRegion" : []}]}
    "warehouses": [{"warehouseId" : "364-01","quantity" : 734,"servicedRegion" : ["<h3>DE</h3>","<h3>AT</h3>"]}]}
    298
```

Those dangling numbers at the beginning and end are easy to rectify - just match on the appropriate tags and then eat the values (don't spit anything out).

Looks like you intended to have a cross-reference file with a *plural* root and singular entries, but crossed your wires along the way.  Easy enough to adapt back to plural if you pay attention to the lines I altered and change them accordingly and properly.

As for your *highlighted concern*, that extra "warehouses" entry, why are you matching on every `/advice_file/product` and starting to spit out line entries if you intend to suppress some of those altogether based on certain criteria?  I'd expect to see something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/advice_file/product[QUALIFYING PREDICATE HERE]" name="xsl:initial-template">
```

...in order to eliminate warehouses entries based on the proper criteria.

It's not an **if** problem - you have a fundamental design flaw in your sheet.

That ought to be enough for you to finish this out and get to where you're going.  I won't do it all for you, as you seem to know enough to take it from here.

Hope that helps.